# How to wait for data from api to be loaded and then perform another action in the UI?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs6

I have a method that gets the userlist from the api and populates the list component. Now what i want to do 
is highlight the first element of the list once the list is loaded from the api.
I have tried the following approach and it is working fine with setTimeout but how can i make it happen without setTimeout function

Here is the code that i tried,

```
public getUserList(){ 
    return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').pipe(tap(x => {
      this.lists = x;
    }))
    .subscribe((data) => {
      setTimeout(() => { 
        this.clickFirstList();
      }, 1000);
    });
  }

clickFirstList() {
    Array.from(this.ulElement.nativeElement.children).forEach((element: HTMLElement, index: number) => {
      if (index === 0) {
        console.log(element);
        element.click();
      }
    });
}
```

Here is the working code on stackblitz. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-brpz2j?file=src/app/search-list.component.ts

Comment: you needn't setTimeout, all under subscribe only execute after the call is completed. NOTE: you not use the data in your code, only to store in "tap" (you want to do it in subscribe? NOTE2: remembe an "Angular style rule": create service to return observables -http.get and others- and subscribe in components

Comment: It is not working in the subscribe. Please edit the code on stackblitz and write it as an answer.

Comment: well, I see your stackblitz. You need use setTimeout -you can use 0 as timer- for give time to Angular to repaint the list, not for wait the call is completed. use `setTimeout(() => {  this.clickFirstList(); });`

Comment: You can use resolver: this will not display all users until you get a result from your API and then you can do what you want inside the subscribe

Comment: Don't manipulate the dom like that in Angular. There is no reason for that. Embrace angular and angular bindings.

Comment: @Eliseo can you how it works in the stackblitz

Comment: @AJT82, You are true. How do i select the first li after the api is loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't manipulate the DOM like that, there is no need. We use angular bindings, and by using those, we can also drastically reduce the code you are currently having. So remove all those DOM manipulations.

First of all we can omit the `lists` call from either parent or child. Now you are performing the get request twice, which doesn't really make sense. I'm keeping the get-request in the child. We can also make the request in OnInit, why would we need to do it in `AfterViewInit`?

```ts
ngOnInit() {
  this.getUserList();
}

public getUserList() {
  return this.http
     // DONT USE 'ANY', type your data using interface or class
    .get<any[]>("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.lists = data;
      // you want to emit initially the first item to parent via output
      // do it here.
      this.onClickList(0, this.lists[0] || {})
    });
 }
```

Also we introduce a new variable `selectedIndex`, which we will change based on the clicked item. Like Jens has done in his answer. You want the first item to be active intially we above pass `0` as the index to the `onClick` function:

```ts
public onClickList(i: number, item: any) {
  this.selectedIndex = i
  this.selectedList.emit(Object.assign({}, item));
}
```

We add that to template like so:

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of lists | filter: searchText; index as i">
  <li [class.active]="i === selectedIndex"
    (click)="onClickList(i, list)">
    {{ list.name }}
  </li>
</ng-container>
```

[**Your forked STACKBLITZ**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z54swf?file=src/app/search-list.component.html)

As mentioned as a comment inside the code. DON'T use `any`, it completely defeats the purpose of **Type**Script, so type your data either with interfaces or classes. I prefer interfaces.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When should we use classes over interfaces?

Comment: I would use them when needed class specific methods to do some business logic (which I wouldn't do anyway). This is a very opinionated question and you would get different answers from different people. Thus I say I prefer interfaces, someone else might say differently :)

Comment: Why not set this.selectedIndex = 0 directly in the callback and skip calling the onclickmethod

Comment: @JensAlenius, sure we could could add `this.selectedIndex = 0` and `this.selectedList.emit(Object.assign({}, this.lists[0]));` to the callback instead, but why would we add "extra lines", when we have the `onClickList` function which does the same?

Comment: I cant see why you would need  emit at all in the example. Is it an @Output somewhere? My answer below should be enough for defaulting the first element

Comment: @JensAlenius, yes, there is an `@Output` in the code. Your answer would be correct and "enough" (like you put it) if there wasn't an `@Output`.

Comment: Oooh in the stackblitz!! Now I see it.  anonymous also wanted the component to publish an event but did not describe it in the question. Good that you looked at the stackblitz.. Thx

Comment: @JensAlenius yeah, the code presented in question is perhaps not really a [mvce], in that you are correct. After reading description, I almost just jump directly into the stackblitz if I see one and don't look too closely at the code in question itself. Except if there is no code presented in question, then I vote to close ;)

Answer (score 0):

Tap also accepts an object map to log next, error, and complete

```
  public getUserList(){ 
    return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    .pipe(
       tap( {
         next: x => {
           console.log('on next', x);
         },
         error: error => {
           console.log('on error', error.message);
         },
         complete: () => {
           console.log('on complete')
           this.clickFirstList()
         }
       }))
       .subscribe((x) => {
        console.log(x)
       });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use following code

```
public getUserList(){ 
    return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').pipe(tap(x => {
      this.lists = x;
    }))
    .subscribe((data) => {
    },
    (err) => {
        // code to execute if request fails
    },
    () => {
    this.clickFirstList();
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would remove clickFirstList. And use css and angular.

I dont now what html element you loop on but lets say its a list
ex: html

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let user of list:let index = index" [class.selected]="index===selectedIndex" (click)="onClick(index)> 
    {{user.Name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

and the css

```
.selected{
   background-color: yellow;
}
```

and in typescript component:

```
selectedIndex = 0; //Default value. 
onClick(index:number){
   this.selectedIndex=index;
}
```

Comment: True. we can do this way but I want to programatically do some condition which is not possible with template. I want to know how you can call the click fist element when the api is loaded. This is not an answer i am lookin for.

Comment: Ok then write the specifically in you question. So you wont get more answers like mine.

Comment: It is already adked in the question. These lines,
 How to wait for data from api to be loaded and then perform another action in the UI?